# Why won't "MyApp.Desktop" launcher appear in "Show Applications"?

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and have created a file for "MyApp" called "MyApp.Desktop". I placed it in the `~/.local/share/applications` directory, but it won't show-up in the GNOME "Show Applications" list. What am I missing?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name[en_US]=MyApp
Exec=/home/myuser/MyApp/MyApp
Icon=/home/myuser/icons/MyApp.png
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the file needs to end with `.desktop` with no capital letters. Linux is case-sensitive.

Secondly, you need to have a `Name=` field before you can declare region-specific ones. Removing `[en_US]` from your file is the simplest fix. You can also have both a `Name=` and `Name[en_US]=` field.

For more information, you can view an example file here: https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/apa.html